# Best way to share logic between teams (Web + Native)

Tags: npm, architecture, shared-libraries, microservices, serverless

We are 3 teams:

1. Website front-end (React)
2. Website back-end (Node.js)
3. Native app (React Native, Node.js)

We want to share logic (e.g. Validations).
As of now I found articles on 3 ways to do so:

1. A NPM Package we will create for our own needs
2. A micro-service with endpoints who carry relevant logic
3. Serverless functions who carry relevant logic

Any other real-life, production suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> Any other real-life, production suggestions?

Kind of - in no specific order:

You could specify the rules in a language/technology agnostic way, and then have your app load them at runtime (or be compiled in during build).  The rules could then exist as a config file, or even be fetched from a remote location (a variation on your options 2 & 3).

Of course, designing a language agnostic rules engine / approach is non-trivial, and depends on what you need the rules to do (how complex, etc). You **might** find a pre-built open source solution that does that.

I have seen people try this, but the projects never succeeded (for unrelated reasons).  One team specified the rules in an Excel sheet.

But there are trade-offs:

1. Performance hit - how to take language agnostic rules and be able to execute them?  This will probably take some translation.  Native code is almost always going to be faster and more efficient.
2. Higher development effort.
3. Added complexity - harder to debug (even if you compensate by developing more mechanisms to assist you do that - which is more development effort).

**Regarding Your Options**

For what it's worth, code / design-time sharing is an obvious approach, which I guess is sufficiently covered by NPM.  I don't know enough about React and Node to know if they have any better ways of doing that.  Normally if I have logic I want to  share I'll use a component which is purpose built (lean as possible, minimal dependencies, intended to be re-used across multiple projects), and ingested in (C# / .Net) at compile/design time.

As an alternative to NPM you could look at dependency injection.  This would allow you to do things like update the logic even after the app was deployed, as long as it can access where ever a newer set of rules are.  So it's a bit like your option 1 (NPM, code level loading) but at runtime, and just once, and your options 2 & 3 - fetched remotely at runtime - the difference being that you're ingesting the logic not firing off questions and receiving answers (less chatty).

Service base rules are good in that they are totally separated, but the obvious trade-offs are availability and performance at runtime.

I don't see a difference in your options 2 & 3 from the stand-point of creating, managing and sharing logic.  The only material impact is on whomever implements and supports that service system.